# dojox.geo.openlayers roadmap?

Tags: openlayers-2, dojo

I'm curious as to the future of [dojox.geo.openlayers](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/geo/openlayers.html).  Presently is seems only to be a solution for positioning widgets on the map but I can imagine developing a suite of map specific dijits such as TOC, filtering, measuring and editing tools and on and on.  Is anyone aware of (or willing to share) a roadmap for future dojox.geo.openlayers work or knowledge of other openlayers dijits?